# Difference between injecting $scope and $rootscope into unit test?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

This always confuse me and was wondering what, how, **why**, and **when** would we use either when writing unit tests.

```
var $rootScope;
beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_) {
  $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
}));
```

### vs

```
var $scope;
beforeEach(inject(function(_$scope_) {
  $scope= _$scope_;
}));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Second approach will be a failure*. You cannot inject a `$scope` as there is no `$scope` service that exists (as opposed to [$rootScope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope) provider) in the injector. If you need to create a child scope from a rootScope, inject $rootScope and do `$scope = $rootScope.$new()`;

Example:-

```
var $rootScope, $scope, $isolatedScope;
beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_) {
  $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
  $scope = _$rootScope_.$new(); //inherited scope
  $isolatedScope =  _$rootScope_.$new(true) //isolated scope
}));

//   .....

beforeEach(function(){
  $controller('myControllThatUsesScope', {$scope:$scope});      
});
```

`$scope` generally is a dynamic or special dependency that gets injected to an angular entity(like a controller, directive linking functions). That is the exact reason why when you instantiate a controller (that has a dependency on $scope) with `$controller` Service you need to explicitly provide `$scope` in locals as opposed to other dependencies (like a service) that are available in the injector and similarly you need to use `$rootScope` to get access to scope methods, like eventing api, inside a service.

Just to be more specific on your question:

- what - Inject `$rootScope` and create child scope if and when you need.
- how  - Already mentioned in the answer on how to inject rootscope.
- why - reasons mentioned in the answer on why you cannot inject a `$scope` but you can inject `$rootScope`
- when - Whenever you need the scope object, whether to provide it to instantiate a controller, test a 2 way bound directive, manually apply in order to invoke a digest cycle(you could as well just use $rootScope) etc...

Comment: nice detailed answer, was wondering if you could shed some light on inherited and isolated scope, and why they're different.

Comment: @Simple-Solution `Scopes can be nested to limit access to the properties of application components while providing access to shared model properties. Nested scopes are either "child scopes" or "isolate scopes". A "child scope" (prototypically) inherits properties from its parent scope. An "isolate scope" does not.` Please [refer this](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#what-are-scopes-).